# How to fetch ooyala image?

Tags: image, preview, ooyala

I've been looking around the web all day long but I'm not able to find a way to get the URL for a video image that's hosted on Ooyala. I read that the URL's vary from video to video, but I wonder if there isn't ANY way to get the image from the embed code.

In case you're wondering, I'm not uploading the vids to Ooyala myself, I'm simply running a site that embeds some Ooyala vids (as well as videos from other sites). Does anyone have a solution, or is there simply no way for me to get a preview image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know on which technology you are working upon. But i have used ruby on rails with ooyala V2. So Ooyala have a ruby on rails module. Which can be downloaded from their site.

Also, u need to have OOYALA_API_KEY,OOYALA_V2_SECRET_CODE. Which u can get by logging into ur ooyala account under developer section.

After getting the module of ruby on rails from ooyala.

The code is simple as follows:

```
 ooyala_obj = Ooyala::API.new(OOYALA_API_KEY,OOYALA_V2_SECRET_CODE)
      thumbnail = ''
      response = ooyala_obj.get("/v2/assets/#{embed_code}/generated_preview_images")
      response.each do |attribute|
        if attribute["url"].present?
          thumbnail = attribute["url"]
          break
        end
      end
      return thumbnail
```

As only embed code will not work, you need to have a verfied signature to get the generated preview image from ooyala which is only done by API KEY AND SECRET CODE.

I hope I helped you..